# How to retrieve data from sql database to check boxes

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, npgsql

I have this code to retrieve data from a database to text boxes on my form.

```
String SLCT = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_code=@client_code";
NpgsqlCommand Select = new NpgsqlCommand(SLCT, conn);
Select.Parameters.AddWithValue("@client_code", client_code);

conn.Open();

using (NpgsqlDataReader read = Select.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (read.Read())
    {
        client_nameTextBox.Text = (read["client_name"].ToString());
        client_addresTextBox.Text = (read["client_addres"].ToString());

    }

    conn.Close();
```

How do I do the same for check boxes?

Datatype in the database is Boolean.

Comment: yourCheckBox.Checked = (bool)yourReader["SomeField"];

Comment: Yup that worked. Thanks.